# How to convert time object into total minutes python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I have objects of the form '00:00:00.0000000' from which I simply want to extract a float number of minutes.  From `import time` I so far have this:

```
>>> reformat = time.strptime('00:05:36.0100000', '%H:%M:%S.%f0')
>>> print reformat
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=5, tm_sec=36, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

It seems like this should follow with something like `time.getminutes(reformat)` or `reformat.minutes()` and voila.  I can't find such an operation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Parse the date string as a datetime.datetime. Since the date string has no year, month or day, the datetime will assume the date to be `1900-1-1`. If we subtract `datetime.datetime(1900,1,1)` we'll obtain a `datetime.timedelta` object which has a [`total_seconds` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds). Conversion to minutes is then easy:

Subtract it from

```
import datetime as DT
t1 = DT.datetime.strptime('00:05:36.0100000', '%H:%M:%S.%f0')
t2 = DT.datetime(1900,1,1)

print((t1-t2).total_seconds() / 60.0)
```

yields

```
5.60016666667
```

Answer (score 6):

if it is a datetime time object i.e. from datetime import time.
you can calculate it simply as

```
timeobject.hour*60+timeobject.minute+timeobject.second/60
```

Since you want minute resolution, I doubt there is need for second or even microsecond accuracy